# Can't click links at all in certain circumstances

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, chrome-extensions

This problem has bothered me for a few months now, but only in very limited circumstances. When I went on medium.com and tried to access my profile, when I clicked to open the navigation, the box dropped down for less than a second before disappearing.

[image]

Even worse, the menu doesn't even appear at all every click. It's about every other click, but I don't think exactly. Double clicking has mixed results, but none too promising. I tried in Safari with the same results.

The even more annoying thing is that in Chrome, I can't left-click on any extensions to access their menus, at all.

[image]

And I'm not 100% sure if this is related, but I've also been having issues installing certain applications, including Wireshark and TrueCrypt 7.2

When I opened the installer, I get two instances of the installer, each of which stall and never finish the initial file verification process (before I can even start the installer).

Comment: Does this only happen with chrome? Does safari have to same issue?

Comment: How odd. Does this also happen if you boot into safe mode?

Comment: @IronCraftMan I have the same issue with Safari

Comment: @JMY1000 I didn't think of that, actually. Just tried though and booting into safe mode does solve the problem of clicking it, but then I run into different weird display issues

Comment: Try booting into Apple Hardware Test / Apple Diagnostics and see if you're having GPU issues.